# Changing DOM order after drag and drop with packey and draggabilly

Tags: javascript, jquery, packery

There is a bug on this code

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/cbhDG

```
docReady(function () {

    var slidesElem = document.querySelector('.slides');
    var slideSize = getSize(document.querySelector('.slide'));
    var pckry = new Packery(slidesElem, {
        rowHeight: slideSize.outerHeight
    });
    // get item elements
    var itemElems = pckry.getItemElements();
    // for each item...
    for (var i = 0, len = itemElems.length; i < len; i++) {
        var elem = itemElems[i];
        // make element draggable with Draggabilly
        var draggie = new Draggabilly(elem, {
            axis: 'y'
        });
        // bind Draggabilly events to Packery
        pckry.bindDraggabillyEvents(draggie);
    }

    // re-sort DOM after item is positioned
    pckry.on('dragItemPositioned', function (_pckry, draggedItem) {
        var index = pckry.items.indexOf(draggedItem);
        var nextItem = pckry.items[index + 1];
        slidesElem.insertBefore(draggedItem.element, nextItem.element);
    });

});
```

When I drag the "first" item to the "last one" the DOM doesn't change and error in console appear.

Any ideas? I'm really struggling to find the error.

I will appreciate all your help

The sample is using: [packery.metafizzy.co](//packery.metafizzy.co) with [draggabilly.desandro.com](//draggabilly.desandro.com)

Comment: Please provide the description for the console error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the index, it should just be

```
var nextItem = pckry.items[ index ];
```

`draggedItem` gives the index of where you put it / the index of where the next item was

Comment: Didn't work. The error stop showing up on console but now the DOM doesn't move or change the items positions, I hope make sense.

Comment: @carlosdv4 I used this here and it works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlbrA Your problem may be with something else

Comment: when I download you code on CodePen, works fine, you can drag and drop with no problem as visual, however the DOM doesn't change as Desandro CodePen example http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/cbhDG  also I see you made the change as the previous answer, however that change stop the DOM moving to the correct place after is dragged in fact I suggest to change the name of "slide" like this one http://codepen.io/carlosdv4/pen/xahAb